# Restoring SVN history links after commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

In Eclipse I moved and renamed a few files and committed. I now understand that I should have used `svn move` and `svn rename` or done `Repair move` in TortoiseSVN before the commit. But I didn't do, and commited. Now the history is not linked for those files. Is it possible to recover the history?

I was using Subclipse before, and I didn't face this problem. But now I don't have Subclipse installed. So I am guessing that if Subclipse is installed, it handles this by changing the refactoring behavior of Eclipse. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have committed the changes the only way to fix this would be to start over.  Delete the items and commit, and then go back and do a proper move and commit.  You might also be able to use svn copy to copy the old item from history if needed.

If you were using Subclipse when you refactor the files they would be moved automatically so you would not have had this problem.

Comment: AFAIK if a file is deleted, and after a few commits, a new file is written into the same path with the same file name, they are considered as the same file and their history is linked. Is this true?

Comment: No. History is not based on the path name.  SVN knows that an item being deleted is the end of its history and an item being created is the start.  It does not matter if they are the same name,

Comment: So deleting the file and then moving in the new version after the fact will accomplish what you want.  That assumes you have the original file to move though too.

Comment: I reverted to the old, healthy commit, and committed again. This restored the history links. After this, I made the changes again with "repair move" etc., and committed. Although there are a few redundant commits, everything seems to be fine now.